# Proof using trinogometric identities

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

Im proving a theorem, the last bit that I have to get is go from:
$$  \sqrt{\frac{2}{n}} \left( \cos{\left[ \theta \left( n -\frac{1}{2} \right) \right]} - \cos{\left[ \theta \left( n -\frac{1}{2} \right) - \theta \right]}  \right) $$

to

$$ \sqrt{\frac{2}{n}} \cos{\left( \theta \left( n -\frac{1}{2} \right)  \right)} \left( 2 -2 \cos{\theta} \right) $$

Im trying applying different identities but couldnt really arrive there. Made like 4 different approaches on paper but cant seem to get there.

Comment: Any clue? Tried developing cos(x)-cos(x-y). Also cos(x+y)-cos(x-y) . and also cos(x+y)-cos(x), then some sines appear and applying identities to those dont get me any further

Comment: I think you will find that the two expressions are equal only for $\theta$ a multiple of $\dfrac{\pi}{n}$.

Comment: Please see [this article on MathSE protocol](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236).
As onerous as the article may appear to you, it provides a defense mechanism against the MathSE forum being used as a *do my homework* forum.  In particular, please see the **Edit-Tools** section of the article, and the portion of the article that discusses *showing work*.  Homework problems are allowed, as long as the protocol is
observed.

Comment: Well, it is not my homework. Im proving a theorem that i want to include in my degrees thesis, but im stuck in that part.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales so are not equal always? $\theta$ is $\frac{i \pi}{n}$ being $i,n$ integers

Comment: For example, it is not true if $n=3$ and $\theta=\pi/2$.

Comment: All I did was draw the graph of the difference of the two functions on desmos dot com and noticed where the zeros were for different values of $n$.